# Is there any reliable website other than google translate to translate from Chinese to English?

Tags: publications, language, translations

So I have come across a paper that will highly beneficial to me and my research group ,but the problem its in chinese and it heavily involves chemical formulas and mathematical data,so its hard to translate using google translate.Is there any site that translates academia papers?

Answer (score 4):

Please pay a mathematical freelancer on Upworks.

Comment: Is there any free alternative?

Comment: @OmkarKedge Translating highly technical texts is difficult. There is no automated translator that can handle it well, and people who do it need a great deal of training in both the discipline and the two languages. Why should it be available for free?

Comment: @Johanna : So the answer is, find a way to squeeze more money from your research financers.

Answer (score -4):

a good tranlate software is DEEPL. Just google for it.

Comment: Among other problems with this answer, DEEPL does not support Chinese.